# jquery: how to escape strings?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have an xml string that wanted to be sent to server:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
                $('#button').click(function() {
                        $.post('http://localhost/a.bc', { cmd:"<cmd cmd_name='login_user'><login_user user_name='binc1' password='pp'/></cmd>"},  function(data) {
                                        alert(data);
                                          $('.result').html(data);
                                          });
                                });
        });

        </script>
```

The white space inside the xml is replaced to '+' when server got it.
Is it possible that I can escape the xml by myself before use $.post so that it will send the escaped version to server. I can unescape the string in the server side.

Or even better, can I send pure XML to server without any escape/unescape dirty things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to escape the string, the JavaScript [escape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) function is at your disposal.

Comment: The `escape()` function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a JavaScript function like encodeURIComponent. Check out the link below for usage and examples.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp